# I have solar panels does the bi-directional service head control power factor?

Tags: power

I have solar panels, had them for three years now. The first two years my summer bill was 3-20 dollars a month. Last year I received to bills in a row that were around 90 dollars. I called to someone come out to see why. The service tech came out and pulled out a laptop. He connected to my outside service head magnetically. It showed a lot of information even Power Factor. The PF reading was .65 I didn't like that so he changed the service out. The new service head read .85 better but I would like and think it should be .9 or better. I asked the rectifier company if they within there panel controlled PF? They said they have nothing to do with that.

So one question is does the outside my bi-directional service head control PF?

The other question is are "utilities companies" required to maintain a PF band?

Comment: I'm not sure where your from, but in my area (canada) PF is currently not considered in our power bills.  My understanding is that the newer 'smart' meters can measure PF but have no control over it.

Answer (score 1):

The power factor is determined by the load. The utility must accommodate whatever the load power factor happens to be. Accommodating a low power factor means that the utility must supply a higher than "normal" current to deliver a given power level. That increases the utility's cost because the transmission losses are increased. It also reduces the amount of power that can be supplied with a given complement of equipment. Utilities often add a surcharge or penalty to large customers if their power factor is low. Few if any utilities charge small customers for low power factor. If there is such a charge, the bill should clearly show it.

The only way to control power factor is to connect capacitors to the supply to compensate for the inductance of the load. That is often done by industrial users and utility companies. The switching can be done automatically using continuous measuring instruments that control either electronic or electromechanical switching equipment. The equipment package would be called a power factor controller. Something like that might be built into some pieces of load equipment but it would not be included in any solar power system equipment.

I am not familiar with the term "service head," but I assume it is the utility service equipment including the revenue meter and equipment used to isolate your solar equipment from the utility in the event of a power outage. That would only affect your bill if the meter was defective. If it was not indicating the correct power factor, it would probably be replaced even if power factor is not used for billing.

A likely cause of your increased bill might be some failed solar cells or a problem with the inverter that converts the solar DC power to AC. Anything that reduces the power supplied by the solar system will increase the power that your loads get from the utility and thus increase your bill.

> So one question is does the outside my bi-directional service head
>   control PF?

No it does not.

> The other question is are "utilities companies" required to maintain a
>   PF band?

They are not required to do so, but they have an economic incentive to do so. However whether they duo so or not, that has no  direct effect on the customer.

More re low power factor:

A distorted load current waveform (non-sinusoidal) can be caused by electronic equipment including motor speed controllers, electronic ballasts in fluorescent lights, electronics in LED lights, power supplies for computers and other types of electronic devices, voltage boosters in microwave ovens, and induction heated cooking elements. A distorted current waveform causes a type of low power factor called distortion power factor. Distortion power reduces the total power factor, but it can only be compensated by filter circuits, simple power factor correction capacitors can not be used.

Electronic equipment can be designed to limit the amount of distortion caused, and there are standards requiring that, but there may be some exemptions and lack of enforcement that could result in considerable distortion. Solar power inverters should be designed to minimize the distortion they might cause, but it is possible that yours may be causing distortion.

Comment: First, thank you for your response. Do utilities companies have a limit to how far they let the power factor sag. I seriously doubt that house could cause the power factor reading at my electrical service meter (service head). So I my mind that means that my "area" has low power factor.

Comment: The power factor at your meter is the power factor of the current through your meter. The power factor of your "area" can only be measured where the current for the area can be measured. I will add more to my answer about power factor.